# Notepad++: Multiple line search & multiple line replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having a battle with a regex. (MOBI creation) 
I have two files: one with XML, the other an HTML table of contents.

The important parts of the XML:

```
<navPoint id="_NeedsHTMLid" playOrder="40">
<navLabel><text>Needs anchor text from link.)</text></navLabel>
...
```

The HTML TOC, of course, looks like:
    schema.org Article Mark-up

======
Hours and hours... worked with Textpad forever. Saw remarks here, now I'm using NotePad++... some of the regex results are different (NOT that I had it working anyway.) `#_[\b(\w\b]`  was returning the ID: now? Not so much!

Does anyone know how to yank both the ID and the anchor text out of these? I'd be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

`#_[\b(\w\b]` is not a valid regex.  Try `_([^"]+)\b`.

Edited: try `[^"]` in place of `\w`.

Comment: You can't have a word boundary between `_` and a character from `\w` since `\w` contains `_`

Comment: You guys rock :) Thanks but no :( both of yours miss Ids separated by a dash.

Comment: Please see my edit. Your original example did not include the hyphen, so I didn't account for that possibility.

Comment: That does work! Why doesn't (>[^<]*)  work then? (Both being used in php once they work in notepad++)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use `(>[^<]*)` in this context.  That would match `>` and all of the characters following it until it hits `<`.  That is very different.  In the example you gave, it would match the following: `>\n`, `>`, `>Needs anchor text from link.)`, `>`, and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the id and the anchor text at the same time:

_(\w+)\b|([a-Z\s.]+[)]+)

Comment: You guys rock :) Thanks but no :( both of yours miss Ids separated by a dash. I got lucky and found two that do the job - bot NOT together, woe is me. (#_[^"]*)  that guy finds the entire anchor. #_ and all... (id=[\"\w+\"]*) THIS guy finds the id's new home id="_". If ever I get them going at the same time, just replace the _ slam and jam, done. Instead of hours and hours of TOC making (ralph)

Comment: Oh lord, I truly tried each of these... nothing went well. Finally I had a piece of luck tonight and got 2 regexes working: independently, no or. Believe me at this point I don't care lol! Elegance is long, long gone.  Every time I hit <enter> this thing posts... excuse me, going to have to make a new one.

Comment: <p class="t2"><a href="#_ID-I-need">anchor text too</a></p>
I get $i and $a. 

Both regexes function well seperately, as I said. Here they are:
(#_[^"]*) === finds #_id-words
(>[^<]*) === finds anchor text

All goes well with php until the anchor regex: puke.

preg_match($idstr, $url_in, $matches); 
...
preg_match($anchorstr, $url_in, $matches); 
PUKE.

Evidently php doesn't like something about that 2nd regex but what on earth? I escaped everything but the kitchen sink.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the ids and the text, go to `Search` > `Find` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   id="([a-zA-Z0-9\-\:\_\.]+)"|<text>(.+?)<\/text>
   ```
2. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
3. Then press `Find All in Current Document`

You can test it with your example at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hM4lM8).

Here's a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2140859) post about valid id names.

I didn't provided you with a Search and Replace solution, since you didn't mentioned anything about a replacement.